# Prove that $\int_X f \, d\mu=\int_Y\mu(f^{-1}[t,\infty)) \, d\mathcal{L}(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the Lebesgue measure on $Y=[0,\infty)$. Let $(X,\mathfrak{B},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $f$ be a nonnegative $\mu$-measurable  function on $X$. Prove that $\int_X f \, d\mu=\int_Y\mu(f^{-1}[t,\infty)) \, d\mathcal{L}(t)$.

I'm learning measure theory and is this question correct? Because I get $\int_X f \, d\mu=\int_Y\mu(f^{-1}[t,\infty)) \, d\mathcal{L}(t)=\mu(f^{-1}[t,\infty))\mathcal{L}([0,\infty))=\infty$ and this is not true when $X$ has finite measure and $f$ is bounded. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$
\int f(x)dx =\int \left [\int 1_{0 < f(x) < y} dy \right]dx
$$Now use the Fubini theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain where I did mistake in my attempt?

Comment: where does your assumption come from? it is not at all obvious.